# Update checkbox and textarea value in mysql db using Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

I have textarea and three checkboxs in my mysql db by default textarea value as null and checkboxs values as `zero(0)`.

when i enter some text in textarea i'm updating text value in my mysql db but i gotta stuck in checkbox things can some one suggest how to update checkbox checked value in mysql db

say for example if checkbox is `checked/clicked` i should be able to update my mysql db with value '1' if not the value will be '0'

> https://jsfiddle.net/07wmpjqf/1/

**db structure**

```
ID  TEXT  ABC  XYZ  LMN
1   NULL   0    0    0
```

Thanks!

**html**

```
<div>
      <textarea class="lb_text" rows="6" cols="50" placeholder="Add text here..."></textarea>
</div>
<div>
    <label>
        <input type='checkbox'>ABC
    </label>
</div>
<div>
    <label>
        <input type='checkbox'>XYZ
    </label>
</div>
<div>
    <label>
        <input type='checkbox'>LMN
    </label>
</div>
    <div>
            <input type="submit" class="lb_save" value="submit">
        </div>
```

**php**

```
if(isset($_POST['lb_text']))
        {   
            $live_blog = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['lb_text']);
            $sql = "update demo set text='".$live_blog."'";
            $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

        }
    }
```

**jquery**

```
$(function(){
    $(".lb_save").click(function(){
        var lb_text = $('.lb_text').val();
        if(lb_text == '')
        {
            alert("Enter Some Text...");
            $('.lb_text').focus();
        }
        else
        {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "index.php",
                data:{
                    lb_text:lb_text,

                },
                success:function(response){
                    alert('successfully updated');
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: in console what values are getting posted.

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju in console currently im not posting any value if i click checkbox value one should be updated in my mysql db any help is appreciated Thanks!

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju I'm updating my textarea entered text value but im unable to update my checked value as 1 in mysql db

Comment: its because you are not posting any value for checkbox in `data` of `$.ajax`

Comment: Yes im not posting currently im surfing like how to send checked value to data in ajax and in mysql update query will u help me out in how to pass checkbox checked value to ajax and in php update query Thanks!

Comment: is your check boxes, hardcoded, i mean only 3 checkboxes??

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju Yes only 3 checkboxes Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add id to your check box and capture th value in jquery.

```
<div>
    <label>
        <input type='checkbox' id="abc">ABC
    </label>
</div>
<div>
    <label>
        <input type='checkbox' id="xyz">XYZ
    </label>
</div>
<div>
    <label>
        <input type='checkbox' id="lmn">LMN
    </label>
</div>
```

and change your ajax data like this,

```
data: {
    lb_text: lb_text,
    abc: $("#abc").is(':checked') ? 1 : 0,
    xyz: $("#xyz").is(':checked') ? 1 : 0,
    lmn: $("#lmn").is(':checked') ? 1 : 0,
},
```

and your query like this,

```
$live_blog = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['lb_text']);
$abc = $_POST['abc']
$xyz = $_POST['xyz']
$lmn = $_POST['lmn']
$sql = "update demo set text='".$live_blog."',ABC='".$abc."',XYZ='".$xyz."',LMN='".$lmn."'";
```

Comment: one help, in php file before updating , `print_r($_POST)` and check q=what you r getting and post here.

Comment: Thank You So Much you solved my issue and made my day Thankful for ur valuable time and code Thanks!!!

Comment: After using print_r($_POST) i'm getting
Array ( [lb_text] => sachin [abc] => 1 [xyz] => 1 [lmn] => 0 )